# How to override function while modifying arguments?

Tags: javascript

I want to override parseInt to remove commas first

Running in tampermonkey on chrome

Ie rather than `parseInt(s)`

It will do

```
s.replace(/,/g, '');
parseInt(s)
```

My current code is

```
(function() {
    // log all calls to setArray
    var proxied = parseInt;
    parseInt = function() {
        arguments[0]=arguments[0].replace(/,/g, '');
        return proxied.apply( this, arguments );
    };
})();
```

I get error "arguments[0].replace is not a function"

Comment: worked for me. please show how you are calling it.

Comment: Please use a SO snippet to provide runnable code. I don't reproduce your problem.

Comment: You can make your own parseInt like this: ```Number.prototype.myOwnParseInt = // your function```

Comment: Plus, that's not a pretty good practice to override default stuff, it could mess with dependencies or the brain of your teammates later. :/

Comment: Please don't mention in your question that it is solved. Instead mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: I can't for the next 6 minutes apparently

Comment: Sorry i'm new to stackoverflow, howcome trincot can edit my question?

Comment: Maybe you should ask him? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sure your argument is a String :

```
(function() {
    // log all calls to setArray
    var proxied = parseInt;
    parseInt = function() {
        arguments[0]=arguments[0].toString().replace(/,/g, '');
        return proxied.apply( this, arguments );
    };
})();
```

**EDIT :**
This solution is better than casting I think because of the definition of the first argument of parseInt:

> The value to parse. If the string argument is not a string, then it is
>   converted to a string (using the ToString abstract operation). Leading
>   whitespace in the string argument is ignored.

**EDIT2 :**
As it's been said in comments: it's not really a good practice. However, if still want to do this, you should also allow the second argument (base)

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: @trincot I needed to explain the difference with casting (the other answer)

Comment: It would be better if the OP would learn where  they went wrong in *calling* the function. But apparently they are happy with these answers... oh well.

Comment: I am using thousand of lines of other people's code so I didn't realise they fed in a number rather than a string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its because you passed it a number.
One possible solution can be casting arguments[0] to a string before calling the replace method on it like

```
(function() {
    // log all calls to setArray
    var proxied = parseInt;
    parseInt = function() {
        arguments[0]=String(arguments[0]).replace(/,/g, '');
        return proxied.apply( this, arguments );
    };
})();
```

Comment: Where did you see in the question they "passed it a number"?

Comment: There are a lot more scenarios that could make that happen. You are just picking one of them as a guess. And OP has just clarified they pass a string (giving an example).

Comment: @nickt, it only works around your problem. You don't know what caused it.

Comment: @trincot How? When a number is passed in it has no replace method. Hence the error. So you need to make sure that it is a string so it will not fail. People will either pass in string or number. So other option would be to check if it is a number and no do the check.

Comment: How? Not passing an argument at all, passing an array, passing a plain object, passing a Date, passing a regex, passing .... lots of things. Casting it to string only remedies  the consequence of a hidden cause.

Comment: I am using thousand of lines of other people's code so I didn't realise they fed in a number rather than a string. Thanks